# UIButton label not respecting text set by completion handler of previous animation when selected

Tags: ios, iphone, animation

On the touchUpInside call of _menuButton, I perform an animation to show the menu with a completion block to change the label of the menu from "open" to "close". That animation works fine, but when you press down on _menuButton it instantly changes from "close" to "menu" even if the user cancels the tap or slides off of the button. The initial text of the button label is "menu".

Not sure if it makes a difference, but my property for _menuButton is:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *menuButton;
```

Animation to load menu:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                         _menuButton.center = CGPointMake(_menuButton.center.x + 120, _menuButton.center.y);
                         _quitButton.center = CGPointMake(_quitButton.center.x + 215, _quitButton.center.y);
                         _rulesButton.center = CGPointMake(_rulesButton.center.x + 215, _rulesButton.center.y);
                         _preferencesButton.center = CGPointMake(_preferencesButton.center.x + 215, _preferencesButton.center.y);
                         _quitButton.alpha = 1.0f;
                         _rulesButton.alpha = 1.0f;
                         _preferencesButton.alpha = 1.0f;
                         _menuButton.alpha = 1.0f;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         _menuButton.titleLabel.text = @"close";
                     }];
```

Animation to unload menu:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50
                     animations:^{
                         [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
                         _menuButton.center = CGPointMake(_menuButton.center.x - 120, _menuButton.center.y);
                         _quitButton.center = CGPointMake(_quitButton.center.x - 215, _quitButton.center.y);
                         _rulesButton.center = CGPointMake(_rulesButton.center.x - 215, _rulesButton.center.y);
                         _preferencesButton.center = CGPointMake(_preferencesButton.center.x - 215, _preferencesButton.center.y);
                         _quitButton.alpha = 0.0f;
                         _rulesButton.alpha = 0.0f;
                         _preferencesButton.alpha = 0.0f;
                         _menuButton.alpha = 0.6f;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         _menuButton.titleLabel.text = @"menu";
                     }];
```

Comment: The others have touched upon the appropriate technique for changing the `title` for a button, so I won't touch upon that. I notice that you're setting the `title` in the completion block. If you want to animate the changing of the text, you can use [`transitionWithView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW112). That can be a useful way of animating an un-animatable property.

Comment: Great suggestion. I like that idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `_menuButton.titleLabel.text = @"close";` to

```
[_menuButton setTitle:@"close" forState:normal];
```

see
[UIButton Class Reference.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)

Answer (score 0):

[UIButton](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html) provides methods for interrogating and setting the title.  The one you're looking for is:

```
- (void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state
```